# USB audio device not fully working after hotplug

Tags: 14.04, sound, usb, pulseaudio, hotplug

Since upgrading (from 12.04) to 14.04.1, when I hotplug my USB headset, it does not work right.  It won't show up in capture controls, sometimes not even in playback devices. I have to fiddle with pavucontrol to even get it to do that. When it does, it thinks it's an input-only device. It tries to use "Monitor of GN 20000 USB Analog Stereo" for input but of course nothing comes over that.  When Skype is active, I can't even select the "non monitor" version of the GN 2000.  But, if I go into pavucontrol, show all input devices (which then includes the GN 2000 monitor), un-mute it, I can then select "GN 20000 USB Analog Stereo" as my input device for Skype (in pauvcontrol), and the GN 2000 once again shows up in the "capture devices" in the audio mixer.

Also, sometimes the GN 2000 comes up in pavucontrol as "Analog Stereo Output" and the only other options in the drop-down are outpt-related, no option for input; this is sometimes fixed by removing and plugging the device back in...and sometimes not.

If I reboot, it all comes up properly. 'pactl exit,' and restarting pulse audio seems to fix it (the stereo duplex issue), but then that causes other problems (like a Skype hang).

Doing a 'pactl list' of the working and non-working configs shows that lines having to do with the GN 2000 and "output: something + input: something" are missing in the non-working config...but we kind of knew that.

I'm really at a loss here.

This is my hardware:

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 5986:0308 Acer, Inc
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 147e:1001 Upek TCS5B Fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0b0e:2000 GN Netcom
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 046d:0821 Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C910
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It is the GN Netcom that has issues. Even after resume, it will show up in lsusb.

```
arecord -l


**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC892 Alt Analog [ALC892 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: U0x46d0x821 [USB Device 0x46d:0x821], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: USB [GN 2000 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: USB [GN 2000 USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: So, it seems related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/841433 Any tips on slowing down the initialization (udev rule? pulseaudio config?) so the usb device is fully initialized when pulseaudio goes to look at it?